# WPF VB.NET Frame get result from Page

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have an app with the main window's main and only control a `Frame`. Now I have several pages which am navigating through using the frame's source property. But now what I want to achieve is if a page is done doing what it's supposed to do it returns some form of alert to the root frame control so that another page can be loaded. Am still new to .net and WPF so any help would be highly appreciated.

Also if there is a better way of doing this, am open to suggestions.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I realised Page have NavigationService in them, so I could just that to go to another page once the current page is done.